# AWS OpsWorks load-based instances by metrics (like EC2 autoscaling)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, autoscaling, aws-opsworks

There is an AWS OpsWorks stack with 2 layers. The first layer generates tasks and store it to a SQS queue, the second layer performs these tasks.

I need to create load-based instances in the second layer, but I see only cpu/ram/load_avg metrics there, it means I have to keep at least one second-layer instance in always-on mode to load more when it's needed.

Is there a way to create instances by metrics (SQS queue length) like in EC2 autoscaling?

I understand I can install the both layers to the first instance, and first layer will run the second, but I need to separate creating queue process and performing tasks process.

Answer (score 1):

There is no integration with autoscaling portion of the AWS Opsworks API. For your particular situation you could use an algorithm to determine if the instance is the first machine, and then run commands to turn off the specific services in the recipe.

```
deploy/after_restart.rb / recipe name

layer = "worker" ## change to whatever you need
leader = node['opsworks']['layers'][layer]['instances'].keys.sort.first 
hostname = node['opsworks']['instance']['hostname']

if leader == hostname
  ...
  command to run and turn off the worker service
  ...
end
```